# a problem when pushViewController with UIViewcontroller

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

my view are fill in back of Navigationbar how can i make it continuous at the buttom of it.

here is my code

```
WebViewController *webViewController = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebController" bundle:nil];         
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:webViewController animated:YES];
[webViewController release];
```

[image]

Comment: You problem is probably not in the pushViewController code, but in the viewController itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it resized properly, but the origin is off. You should try setting the frame of the WebViewController's view:

```
CGRect frame = webViewController.view.frame;
frame.origin.x = 0;
frame.origin.y = 0;
[webViewController.view setFrame:frame];
```

Comment: thanks David
i try your code and it not work, cause from i load from IB
did you have a solution on IB?

Comment: I'm not really sure, it's a little weird. It should resize and be placed correctly. If you post some more relevant code, I might have more insight.

Comment: when i set my topbar to translucent uiview be apper under topbar
but when set it to not translucent it will continuous at the buttom(work correct!)